# Calculate multiple moving average crossovers

Tags: python, moving-average

I want to calculate multiple moving average crossovers.

My goal is to start with short = 20 and long = 21. As soon as the short moving average crosses the long, i will go long on a specific underlying. I'd like to increase my long variable from 21 to 200 and then start from the beginning with short = 21 and long = 22 and repeat the process.

My nested loop looks like this:

```
#Calculate moving averages first
for GD in range(20,200,1):
    aapl[GD] = aapl.Adj_Close.rolling(GD).mean()

#Calculate MA crossovers
short = 20
long = 21
while short < 200:
    while long < 200:
        aapl[short,long] = np.where(aapl[short] > aapl[long],1,0)
        long = long + 1
    short = short + 1
```

How can i change my code such that the nested loop will repeat until I've calculated all possible crossovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `long` each iteration of the outer loop. Setting it once won't work, it needs to be set every time. I gather you want it to be one greater than `short`, so like this:

```
short = 20
while short < 200:
    long = short + 1
    while long < 200:
        aapl[short,long] = np.where(aapl[short] > aapl[long],1,0)
        long = long + 1
    short = short + 1
```

Then you can simplify both loops by using `for` loops to iterate over ranges. A single `for` loop will handle initialization, looping, and incrementing the loop variable all in one line.

```
for short in range(20, 200):
    for long in range(short + 1, 200):
        aapl[short,long] = np.where(aapl[short] > aapl[long],1,0)
```